# Stale cache issue - question from almost 14 days ago appears in recent stream

Tags: bug, caching

I observed this earlier today, so I don't know if it's reproducible.  But, I'll post everything I know about this in the hopes that someone can do something about it.

Note:  I'm experiencing this with the new navigation.

So this morning, I saw a question with a title that I would want to edit. I would be sure that there were other things that I could do with it.

[image]

Seems routine, right?  So I click on the question and realize *I had beaten myself by almost 14 days.*

[image]

Thinking that it's a very, very strange caching bug, I rush back to confirm that it's not due to any wonky state on my behalf...but to no avail.

The time on the question is congruent to 1 August:

[image]

...but that doesn't make sense, since the top bar is [reporting events that happened **today**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2015-08-13%2002:17:05Z)!

[image]

A quick refresh of the page was able to sort me out, though.  Even so, this was *bizarre*.

How'd I wind up in this state?  What was going on?  Could it be due to some of the moves of infrastructure recently?  Could a cache have decided to overzealously hold on to something?

Comment: Go to the main page, select a question, select back. You'll notice that you are not on the page you were previously viewing This happens on meta as well as the main site. But I only started noticing this with the new nav, not sure if it existed before that.

Comment: I've seen old questions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive too. No obvious reason for them to be there, not edited or anything.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  I get that, but *two weeks*?  I've visited Stack Overflow on this machine *yesterday*!

Comment: It seems to be since the last time you refreshed the page there, not necessarily visited the page but refreshed. If that makes any sense.

Comment: I thought Community sometimes bumped old questions? Also, were there deleted recent answers, or deleted recently modified answers?

Comment: There are multiple meta Q&A's about caching already, I don't know if it's confirmed by the SE developers yet that it's broken. Of course the reputation dropdown is up to date, that's filled by an AJAX request if you open  it. :)

Comment: What "stream" are you talking about by the way? I don't have new-nav, but I sometimes get questions that are many years old in the questions list of the tags I'm interested in (search: *[tag1] or [tag2] or [tag3] or [tag4]...*). I noticed this the first time 3 or 4 months ago, but only on the mobile site. I also noticed this a couple of weeks ago on the desktop site. They usually appear at the end of the first page and were active many years ago.

Comment: Just posted on MSE as well: [Pressing browser's back button takes you to a few days ago's homepage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263706/pressing-browsers-back-button-takes-you-to-a-few-days-agos-homepage).

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, I do happen to be using the new nav.  I'll add that into the question.